# Running QML application: black window

Tags: windows, qt, qml, cross-platform

I have Qt 5.7.1 \ QML application built on Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 x32, which works on "native" computer and has been succesfully tested on other systems: Windows XP (Virtual Box) and Windows 8 \ 10 (real computers).

But there's one more computer with Windows 7 Professional SP1 x32, where the running app looks as:

[image: Bug with app: image in the top-left corner is background picture which normally fills the window]

(Image in the top-left corner is background picture which normally fills the window).

I have no direct access to the last machine, but here is what I know about it:

- CPU: Intel, 2.6 GHz
- RAM: 2 Gb
- Videocard: Intel HD Graphics
- Screen resolution: 1280x1024

What's the problem and how can I fix the issue?

Comment: Does the machine support OpenGL? Try to run the application from console/command line to see if than will print out some warnings.

Comment: Update the graphics driver on the machine. Try different [settings for the graphics driver](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#graphics-drivers) used by Qt.